# Standard MergeSort Algorithm

Tags: algorithm, sorting, recursion, merge, mergesort

I am currently working with a pretty standard Merge Sort file, but am having some issues. I'm fairly new to data structures, so don't really understand completely what is going on. Any tips would be nice as well. Thanks.

Here is the code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct CELL *LIST;
struct CELL {
    int element;
    LIST next;
}

LIST merge(LIST list1, LIST list2);
LIST split(LIST list);
LIST MergeSort(LIST list);
LIST MakeList();
void PrintList(LIST list);

int main()
{
    LIST list;

    list = MakeList();
    PrintList(MergeSort(list));
}

LIST MakeList()
{
    int x;
    LIST pNewCell;
    if(scanf("%d", &x) == EOF) return NULL;
    else {
        pNewCell = (LIST) malloc(sizeof(struct CELL));
        pNewCell->next = MakeList();
        pNewCell->element = x;
        return pNewCell;
    }
}

void PrintList(LIST list)
{
    while(list != NULL) {
        printf("%d\n", list->element);
        list = list->next;
    }
}

LIST MergeSort(LIST list)
{
    LIST SecondList;

    if (list == NULL) return NULL;
    else if (list->next == NULL) return list;
    else {
        SecondList = split(list);
        return merge(MergeSort(list), MergeSort(SecondList));
    }
}

LIST merge(LIST list1, LIST list2)
{
    if (list1 == NULL) return list2;
    else if(list2 == NULL) return list1;
    else if(list1->element <= list2->element){
        list1->next = merge(list1->next, list2);
        return list1;
    }
    else {
        list2->next = merge(list1, list2->next);
        return list2;
    }
}

LIST split(LIST list)
{
    LIST pSecondCell;

    if (list == NULL) return NULL;
    else if (list->next == NULL) return NULL;
    else {
        pSecondCell = list->next;
        list->next = pSecondCell->next;
        pSecondCell->next = split(pSecondCell->next);
        return pSecondCell;
    }
}
```

And the errors that I get (on multiple platforms) are

```
prog.c:10:6: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘merge’
 LIST merge(LIST list1, LIST list2);
      ^~~~~
prog.c: In function ‘MergeSort’:
prog.c:53:16: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘merge’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
         return merge(MergeSort(list), MergeSort(SecondList));
                ^~~~~
prog.c:53:16: warning: return makes pointer from integer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
         return merge(MergeSort(list), MergeSort(SecondList));
                ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
prog.c: At top level:
prog.c:57:6: error: conflicting types for ‘merge’
 LIST merge(LIST list1, LIST list2)
      ^~~~~
prog.c:53:16: note: previous implicit declaration of ‘merge’ was here
         return merge(MergeSort(list), MergeSort(SecondList));
                ^~~~~
```

Comment: The recursive merge will take up O(n) stack space, not an issue for learning, but would be an issue for a large list. If interested, you might consider implementing a [bottom up merge sort for lists - wiki example](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort#Bottom-up_implementation_using_lists), which uses the same merge() function, but uses an array of pointers to nodes to store temporary lists instead of splitting them. It's faster than splitting lists, but it's faster still to move a list to an array, sort the array, and create a new list from the sorted array.

Answer (score 0):

This is wrong:

```
typedef struct CELL *LIST;
struct CELL {
    int element;
    LIST next;
}
```

Try this instead:

```
typedef struct CELL {
    int element;
    struct CELL *next;
} CELL, *LIST;
```

Notice that `next` has to be a pointer, not another `CELL` struct.

The first of your error messages is just pointing out that you missed the semicolon after your declaration of `struct CELL`. (This is also why the declaration of `merge()` is being disregarded.)

Comment: Oh! I missed the semi-colon. Sounds about right. Thanks for the help!